# Build Failing in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build

When I am trying to run my app, Gradle is failing to make the build. 
It is returning this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
>   class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have files bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar or similar which conflicts with Android Studio.

Please removed those jar files from Android sdk and java
for example
Mac OS:
android-sdk-macosx/tools/lib/ and /Library/Java/Extensions/
Windows OS:
Android sdk installed path and Java

and delete .gradle folder from the home directory from your project.

Rebuild the project again, it will help to gradle to load and build the project